# Using Matrix with Playa Fields and Stash set_list

Tags: matrix, playa, stash

I'm using {exp:stash:set_list} along with a few Matrix fields, but when I use {exp:stash:get_list} in my view template to retrieve the values nothing is returned. Here's barebones example of what I'm using.

**Model template:**

```
{stash:embed:layouts:template}

{exp:stash:set_list
  name="people_entry:{segment_2}"
  parse_tags="yes"
  parse_depth="2"
}

  {exp:channel:entries
    channel="people"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
    limit="1"
    status="open"
  }

        {stash:people_title}{title}{/stash:people_title}

        {exp:stash:set_list:nested
          name="name_{entry_id}"
          parse_tags="yes"
        }
          {matrix_field_1}
            {stash:people_name}
                {playa_field}
                    {name}
                {/playa_field}
            {/stash:people_name}
          {/matrix_field_1}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}  

        {exp:stash:set_list:nested
          name="position_{entry_id}"
          parse_tags="yes"
        }
          {matrix_field_2}
            {stash:people_position}
                {playa_field}
                    {position}
                {/playa_field}
            {/stash:people_position}
          {/matrix_field_2}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}

{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

**View template:**

```
{exp:stash:get_list
    name="people_entry:{segment_2}"
}

    {people_title}

    {exp:stash:get_list:nested
        name="name_{entry_id}"
    }
        {people_name}
    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}

    {exp:stash:get_list:nested
        name="position_{entry_id}"
    }
        {people_position}
    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}

{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Using EE 2.7.3 with Stash 2.4.8 and Matrix 2.5.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner nested list needs to be assigned a context that identifies it as belonging to a specific row in the outer list - in this case `{entry_id}` would be a good choice since it is a unique value. Note that I have assumed your playa field is returning a single result - if not you would need another nested list to capture each playa entry and associate it with the parent matrix row_id.

```
  {exp:stash:set_list
    name="people_entry"
    context="{segment_2}"
    parse_tags="yes"
    parse_depth="2"
  }
    {exp:channel:entries
      channel="people"
      disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
      limit="1"
      status="open"
    }
        {stash:people_title}{title}{/stash:people_title}

        {!-- unique reference to child list  --}
        {stash:entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry_id}

        {!-- nested list --}
        {exp:stash:set_list:nested
          name="names"
          context="{entry_id}"
          parse_tags="yes"
          parse_depth="2"
        }
          {matrix_field_1}

            {stash:name}
              {playa_field limit="1"}
                  {name}
              {/playa_field}
            {/stash:name}

          {/matrix_field_1}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}  

    {/exp:channel:entries}

  {/exp:stash:set_list}
```

When you get the list the entry id of the outer get_list row is passed to the nested get_list so that the list associated with that particular row is retrieved:

```
  {exp:stash:get_list name="people_entry" context="{segment_2}"}

      {people_title}

      {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="names" context="{entry_id}" prefix="nested"}

          {nested:name}

      {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}

  {/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to capture the entryid as a stash var so you can call it instead of entry_I'd because entry_id doesn't exist when calling the get_list.

```
{stash:embed:layouts:template}

{exp:stash:set_list
name="people_entry:{segment_2}"
parse_tags="yes"
parse_depth="2"
}

{exp:channel:entries
channel="people"
disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
limit="1"
status="open"
}

    {stash:people_title}{title}{/stash:people_title}
    //Capture entryID
    {stash:entryid}{entry_id}{/stash:entryid}
    {exp:stash:set_list:nested
      name="name_{entry_id}"
      parse_tags="yes"
    }
      {matrix_field_1}
        {stash:people_name}{name}{/stash:people_name}
      {/matrix_field_1}
    {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}  

    {exp:stash:set_list:nested
      name="position_{entry_id}"
      parse_tags="yes"
    }
      {matrix_field_2}
        {stash:people_position}{position}{/stash:people_position}
      {/matrix_field_2}
    {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}

{/exp:stash:set_list}



{exp:stash:get_list
name="people_entry:{segment_2}"
}

{people_title}

{exp:stash:get_list:nested
    name="name_{entryid}" //Unsure of syntax here, could try…
    name="name_{stash:entryid}"
}
    {people_name}
{/exp:stash:get_list:nested}

{exp:stash:get_list:nested
    name="position_{stash:entryid}"} //stashed entryid var
    {people_position}
{/exp:stash:get_list:nested}

{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the Matrix field contains Playa entries. Will update my example.